# Your Gemfile lists the gem more than once. could cause errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

**I am currently getting these messages below when i run bundle install**

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem sqlite3 (= 1.3.5) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.

Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-rails (= 2.10.0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.

Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-rails (= 2.10.0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.

Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (= 0.12.2) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
```

I am using Postgresql with Heroku and I believe I am using Postgresql in both my development and testing. I recently migrated/switched from sqlite to postgresql.

**Do I still need the sqlite3 gems in :development or in :development, :test ?**

**And lastly, is there a difference between :development & :development, :test ?**

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: xxxxxx_development
  pool: 5
  username: xxxxxx
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: xxxxxx_development
  pool: 5
  username: xxxxxx
  password:
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem "bootstrap-sass"
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'

gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
gem 'pg_search'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
end

# Test gems on Macintosh OS X
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
  gem 'rack-google_analytics'
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are repeating putting sqlite in the development group here:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
end
```

You can delete your second development group listing here as it adds nothing - you've already put them in development and test in the first statement.  Similarly by putting pg outside of any group it's available in all, so adding it to production is a duplicate listing.

A rewrite of your gemfile COULD be:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem "bootstrap-sass"
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'

# gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
gem 'pg_search'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
  gem 'rack-google_analytics'
end
```

Also, one friendly tip from someone who's felt the pain: try to use the same db in development as production. I know it can be tricky to get postgres set up locally at first but once it's there it's rock solid and very easy to use. You will risk far fewer bugs due to differences (for example with searching text within fields iirc) between PG and SQLite implementations.

With no sqlite:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem "bootstrap-sass"
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'

gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
gem 'pg_search'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rack-google_analytics'
end
```

Comment: ic, so in the first statement i am listing the gems in both development and test environments. I thought so but wanted to make sure. Thanks. :)

Comment: Can I make a suggestion too - you may want to go to the effort of installing Postgres locally for development and using the same db in production as development. Far less pain in the long run.

Comment: ic, my database.yml file is using postgresql in development and testing. so should i just delete the sqlite3 gems all together. Or how could i check what i am using?

Comment: Yes - if you are using postgres locally, and have it set up you don't need sqlite.

Comment: Then you can take pg out of the production group and just leave it in there at the top without restriction.

Comment: awesome. which leads to my last problem. for some reason my bundle install was also mentioning -- Gems in the group production were not installed. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you run bundle install since making the above changes?

Comment: Yea, I also have rack-google-analytics in production. so now i get this 
    Gems in the group production were not installed.
    Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

Comment: Is this for bundle install locally? That you're getting that error - or in production?

Comment: Now you definitely lost me. I just input bundle install on my console....so is that a yes to your question....I believe it is locally.

Comment: Oh hang on I do seem to have lost your google analytics gem in my edits - let me put that back in.

Comment: So can you try the edited gemfile above, at the bottom of my answer, and see if it now ```bundle install```s properly

Comment: yea i am still receiving that error. Well its not much of an error since its all green when i run bundle install. but I find it strange still.

Comment: is it pushing to heroku okay?

Comment: You may just need to manually ```bundle uninstall``` the offending gems and then re-run bundle install, to see if that helps.

Comment: well it all pushed to heroku just fine :). the website didn't crash. and google analytics seems to be working well. So ill take this as a victory lol. thanks for your help and the great explanation.

Comment: Oh wait... I am being dim. You mean when you are in development environment and run Bundle Install you get a message saying ```Gems in the group production were not installed```? That's normal. It's just telling you that because you put some gems in a group that is ONLY installed in production, they have NOT been installed now because you're in the development environment. Make sense?

Comment: i.e. if you have gems in a group named :production those gems are only installed when bundle install is run in the production environment, gems in the group :test are installed only in the test environment, and in group :development in development, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using pg in all environments than remove the sqlite3 gem.

The difference between :development & :development, :test is that :development, :test is for gems that need to be included in both those environments. :development is for :development only gems.

Answer (score 1):

You have gem sqlite3,pg ,respec-rails more then once in same environment ,you need to remove the duplication of same gem.

Edit your gem file as follows:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem "bootstrap-sass"
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end


group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: you don't need ```guard-rspec``` in the development group